# Dependent dropdown into an Ajax AddMore

Tags: ajax

I used a dependent dropdown into an Ajax AddMore, so I checked the code of [Ajax Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), [class AjaxAddMore](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_api_example!src!Form!AjaxAddMore.php/class/AjaxAddMore/8.x-1.x) and more.
I have several versions that all have a problem; on this one, the behavior of the AddMore overwrites the first form.

Does someone with experience have a solution, please?

```php
namespace Drupal\export\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class TestFilteringStep6Form extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
      return 'test_filtering_step6';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    if ($num_of_filter === NULL) {
      $form_state->set('counter', 1);
      $num_of_filter = 1;
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_of_filter; $i++) {
      $form['filter_fieldset'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Filtre ' . $num_of_filter . ' :'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="add-remove-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ];

      $form['filter_fieldset'][$i]['field'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => ['(Activités) Nom' => '(Activités) Nom', '(Résultats) Score' => '(Résultats) Score'],
        '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Sélection d\'un champs -'),
        '#ajax' => [
          'wrapper' => 'conditiontype-container-wrapper',
          'callback' => '::promptConditionTypeCallback',
        ],
      ];
      $selected_field[$i] = $form_state->getValue(array('filter_fieldset', $i, 'field'));

      // container :
      $form['filter_fieldset'][$i]['conditiontype_container'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'conditiontype-container-wrapper'],
      ];

      if (!empty($selected_field[$i])) {
        if ($selected_field[$i] == '(Activités) Nom') {
          $form['filter_fieldset'][$i]['conditiontype_container']['type'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => ['Activité1' => 'Activité1', 'Activité2' => 'Activité2', 'Activité3' => 'Activité3'],
            '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Sélection d\'un type -'),
            '#default_value' => !empty($form_state->getValue(array('filter_fieldset', $i, 'conditiontype_container', 'type'))) ? $form_state->getValue(array('filter_fieldset', $i, 'conditiontype_container', 'type')) : '',
          ];
        }
        if ($selected_field[$i] == '(Résultats) Score') {
          $form['filter_fieldset'][$i]['conditiontype_container']['type'] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => ['Score1' => 'Score1', 'Score2' => 'Score2', 'Score3' => 'Score3'],
            '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Sélection d\'un type -'),
            '#default_value' => !empty($form_state->getValue(array('filter_fieldset', $i, 'conditiontype_container', 'type'))) ? $form_state->getValue(array('filter_fieldset', $i, 'conditiontype_container', 'type')) : '',
          ];
        }

        if ($form_state->get('counter') > 1) {
          $form['filter_fieldset'][$i]['conditiontype_container']['remove_filter'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Supprimer le filtre ' . $num_of_filter),
            '#submit' => ['::subtractOneToCounter'],
            '#ajax' => [
              'callback' => '::returnFilterFieldsetCallback',
              'wrapper' => 'add-remove-wrapper',
            ],
          ];
        }
      }
    }
    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['actions']['add_filter'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Ajouter un filtre'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOneToCounter'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::returnFilterFieldsetCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'add-remove-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

  /**
   * Callback des select
   */
  public function promptConditionTypeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    return $form['filter_fieldset'][$num_of_filter]['conditiontype_container'];
  }

  /**
   * Callback des boutons add_filter et remove_filter
   */
  public function returnFilterFieldsetCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['filter_fieldset'];
  }

  public function addOneToCounter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    $form_state->set('counter', $num_of_filter + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function subtractOneToCounter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    if ($num_of_filter > 1) {
      $form_state->set('counter', $num_of_filter - 1);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Fonction pour remplir le menu déroulant du type.
   */
  public static function getTypeDropdownOptions($selected_field) {
    switch ($selected_field) {
      case '(Activités) Nom':
        $options = ['Activité1' => 'Activité1', 'Activité2' => 'Activité2', 'Activité3' => 'Activité3'];
        break;

      case '(Résultats) Score':
        $options = ['Résultat1' => 'Résultat1', 'Résultat2' => 'Résultat2', 'Résultat3' => 'Résultat3'];
        break;
    }
    return $options;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is my solution

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class TestFilteringStep8Form extends FormBase
{

  public function getFormId()
  {
      return 'test_filtering_step8';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    if ($num_of_filter === NULL) {
      $field = $form_state->set('counter', 1);
      $num_of_filter = 1;
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

    $form['filter_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Filtres :'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="add-remove-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['filter_fieldset']['conditiontype_container'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'conditiontype-container-wrapper'],
    ];

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_of_filter; $i++) {

      $form['filter_fieldset']['conditiontype_container']['field'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => ['(Activités) Nom' => '(Activités) Nom', '(Résultats) Score' => '(Résultats) Score'],
        '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Sélection d\'un champs -'),
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::promptConditionTypeCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'conditiontype-container-wrapper',
        ],
      ];

      $selected_field = $form_state->getValue(['filter_fieldset', 'conditiontype_container', 'field', $i]);
      $type_options = static::getTypeDropdownOptions($selected_field);

      if (!empty($selected_field)) {
          $form['filter_fieldset']['conditiontype_container']['type'][$i] = [
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#options' => $type_options,
            '#empty_option' => $this->t('- Sélection d\'un type -'),
          ];
      }
    }

    $form['filter_fieldset']['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['filter_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Ajouter un filtre'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOneToCounter'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::returnFilterFieldsetCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'add-remove-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
    // If there is more than one name, add the remove button.
    if ($num_of_filter > 1) {
      $form['filter_fieldset']['actions']['remove_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Supprimer le filtre ' . $num_of_filter),
        '#submit' => ['::subtractOneToCounter'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::returnFilterFieldsetCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'add-remove-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
  }

  /**
   * Callback des select conditions et type.
   */
  public function promptConditionTypeCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    return $form['filter_fieldset']['conditiontype_container'];
  }

  /**
   * Callback des boutons add et remove.
   */
  public function returnFilterFieldsetCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    return $form['filter_fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * Incrémente le compteur
   */
  public function addOneToCounter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    $add_button = $num_of_filter + 1;
    $form_state->set('counter', $add_button);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Decrémente le compteur.
   */
  public function subtractOneToCounter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $num_of_filter = $form_state->get('counter');
    if ($num_of_filter > 1) {
      $remove_button = $num_of_filter - 1;
      $form_state->set('counter', $remove_button);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Fonction pour remplir le menu déroulant du type.
   */
  public static function getTypeDropdownOptions($selected_field)
  {
    switch ($selected_field) {
      case '(Activités) Nom':
        $options = ['Activité1' => 'Activité1', 'Activité2' => 'Activité2', 'Activité3' => 'Activité3'];
        break;

      case '(Résultats) Score':
        $options = ['Résultat1' => 'Résultat1', 'Résultat2' => 'Résultat2', 'Résultat3' => 'Résultat3'];
        break;
    }
    return $options;
  }
}
```